# storing in cell arrays slows down my code even with preallocation

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell

I have a function which contains `for` loops. In these loops I construct some matrices, I call them potential, and then I multiply them in some other matrix, I call it source. Since I want to use this function in a `for` loop for which only the source matrix is changing, I want to store the potential matrices to ignore excessive calculation in  the `for` loop.

I have used a 3D cell array to store the potential matrices but the time for this is more than running the function for once, I mean multiplying the source and potential without saving the potentials. (the time for storing without multiplying is more than multiplying without storing).

I used the preallocation `A=cell(N)` . Why this happens?

Comment: If the output sizes are the same across all iterations, consider using multidimensional arrays  instead of cell arrays.  On storing data into cell arrays, perform as much computation as possible before  saving into cell arrays and store as little as possible into them.

Comment: @Divakar If I could store them into a 5D arrays, will it be better than a 3D cell array?

Comment: 5D numeric arrays? I would like to think yes to that.

Comment: @Divakar yes, 5D numeric arrays, since instead of storing each matrix into one cell I have to save it as a matix.

Comment: Just make sure that you have lesser number of indices as you go higher up in the dimensions. So, arrange your data accordingly.